# "truncate-create as select" instead of update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a table with big data, and I want to update it. I have a method to do that. Frist, copying the original table and trunc it. After that I will use create as select from copy of table. So I wont use update expressions. Is it more effective?

Comment: Why do you want to add extra processing load on the CPU and memory for copying that whole data ? And Where are you inserting the new values/updating ? 

And an update command would just acquire locks and take the rows into buffer which are supposed to be edited.

Comment: I heart that select is much more effective than update, esspecially in oracle db.

Comment: So where is the update command used ?

Comment: create table1_copy as select t1.c1,t1.c2,t2.c3 from table1 t1, table2 t2     c3 field is updated field from table2 to table1       then; trunc table1 and insert into table1 select * from table1_copy

Comment: There are a couple of questions that come up first in order to answer your question:
How big is the table in terms of rows?
How much percent of those rows will be updated?
Are there any foreign key constraints on the original table?
Are there any indexes on the original table?

It is true that sometimes CTAS operations (create table as select) can speed up your update process because they don't have to maintain referential integrity nor maintain indexes. However, not always this approach is suitable for the application.

Comment: Have you ever hear or use that method? Because it's using now in a project of my campany.

Comment: In very specific cases this method may be more effective. You haven't provided enough info to even guess though. Try answering some of gvenzl questions.

Comment: Another thing to consider is if records are deleted in the original source.  If that's the case, it does add to the mertis of doing a full truncate and reload.  Think @gvenzl's comments are on target -- can you answer those?  The actual mechanics of doing a truncate-reload are very simple.

Comment: there is no foreing key or index in the original table. And table row and percent of rows are flexible. What will be changed by row num and percecnt of rows updated?

Comment: For example, if you just update 10% or less of the actual rows within the table then I doubt that recreating the entire dataset via insert will be more efficient than an update with some appropriate indexing on. Except the 10% reside within a single partition then it might be more beneficial again. If there are no indexes or foreign keys on the table then I would first look at what actually slows down your update and whether maybe a index would help you. Also parallel query might be a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question really depends on how many rows are affected by the update.  Obviously, copying 100,000,000 rows into another table to update one row is not effective.  To update all of them it might be beneficial, because inserts are usually faster than updates.

Before going down this path, I would want to be understand how many rows are being updated.  If not very many are, then appropriate indexing might improve the performance of the updates.

However, the logic for your approach isn't quite right.  I would be inclined to do:

```
create table temp_copy as
    select . . .
    from bigtable . . .;
```

Your logic goes in the `select`.  Then, truncate the big table and reinsert:

```
truncate table bigtable;

insert into bigtable
    select *
    from temp_copy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whhi truncate the table?
I assume there is no constraint on your table (if you can't do a truncate!).
You are more simple whit the commande rename;
It will be quicly as the others methods.
You can do something like that (I take your code):

Your code:

```
truncate  table table1; 
insert into table1 select * from table1_copy
```

replace by:

```
drop table table1 ;
alter table table1_copy rename to table1;
recreate index of  table1
```

Comment: An issue with this approach is that all indexes, triggers, constraints, tablespace assignments, partitioning, etc will be lost when the table is dropped, and thus would need to be recreated. In addition, all objects such as packages, procedures, functions, etc which reference this table will be invalidated.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, but I suppose there is no constraints like fk (if you have fk, you couldn't truncate your table). For indexing, it will be faster to do this approach to. For others information (tablespaces, partitioning, triggers...) you could find easily the informations. I suppose you don't do that to during your production (whith the truncate method, time with incorrect values could be great). So ok you are invalidating some procedures, but it's just for one second. If the goal is to minimize intervention time, maybe it could be a good approach